# ClusterAuthorizationException in Kafka while creating topic

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, sasl, confluent-platform

Our Confluent Kafka is installed on AWS EC2. We are using SASL/SSL security protocol and LDAP for user authentication.

The following exception occurs when trying to create a topic:

```
ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Error when handling request: clientId=2, correlationId=0, api=UPDATE_METADATA, body={controller_id=2,controller_epoch=1,broker_epoch=8589934650,topic_states=[],live_brokers=[{id=2,end_points=[{port=9092,host=dfdp-080060041.dfdp.com,listener_name=PLAINTEXT,security_protocol_type=0},{port=9093,host=dfdp-080060041.dfdp.com,listener_name=SASL_SSL,security_protocol_type=3}],rack=null},{id=1,end_points=[{port=9092,host=dfdp-080060025.dfdp.com,listener_name=PLAINTEXT,security_protocol_type=0},{port=9093,host=dfdp-080060025.dfdp.com,listener_name=SASL_SSL,security_protocol_type=3}],rack=null},{id=0,end_points=[{port=9092,host=dfdp-080060013.dfdp.com,listener_name=PLAINTEXT,security_protocol_type=0},{port=9093,host=dfdp-080060013.dfdp.com,listener_name=SASL_SSL,security_protocol_type=3}],rack=null}]} (kafka.server.KafkaApis)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.ClusterAuthorizationException: Request Request(processor=3, connectionId=10.80.60.13:9093-10.80.60.41:53554-0, session=Session(User:$BEB000-DRJTO9PK3C7L,dfdp-080060041.dfdp.com/10.80.60.41), listenerName=ListenerName(SASL_SSL), securityProtocol=SASL_SSL, buffer=null) is not authorized
```

Comment: btw, "Confluent Kafka" is not a thing.. All documentation says "Confluent Platform"

Comment: @aniket-saha Have you setup Kafka ACLs?  https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authorization.html What is effective ACL for the user that "is not authorized"?

Comment: @cricket-007 I guess existence of "confluent-kafka" tag in SO legalizes the use of the term :)

Comment: @mazaneicha we are trying to create topic using root user.....yes, we have set up kafka ACLs....... # ACL properties
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer

Comment: Local root on some node has no special meaning to Kafka with SASL_SSL security. And your error says that broker attempts to authorize user `User:$BEB000-DRJTO9PK3C7L,dfdp-080060041.dfdp.com/10.80.60.41` (this is in user,hostname/hostIP format). So maybe you forgot to `kinit` if you're using Kerberos for SASL?

Comment: @mazaneicha we are using keytab for user authorization.

Comment: @aniket-saha Keytab is used for **authentication** via Kerberos, not for **authorization**. As you confirmed, **authorization** in your case is done via Kafka ACLs, i.e. Kafka brokers apply ACL rules based on client identity. Your error shows that client identity is `$BEB000-DRJTO9PK3C7L` which looks like a local (windows?) machine account, not part of Kerberos realm.

Answer (score 0):

`ClusterAuthorizationFailed` may indicate that your client is configured to attempt an operation that it doesn't have permission to do from the server.

Namely, `allow.auto.create.topics` and `enable.idempotence` are both set to `true` by default, and the server can be configured to disallow those, leading you to an extremely misleading error message of `ClusterAuthorizationFailed`.

This page in the docs may help you find other settings that could lead to you getting that error:

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#operations_resources_and_protocols